# D3 update graph after data changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a problem with understanding how update works. My goal is that the fill changes its value when data changes its values. After running the following code in a HTML-file I write e.g. `board_state[7][9] = 1` in the console and then `drawBoard()`. Now it adds 10 more rect-Elements to each g instead of updating their value. How can I update the current one with the changed values without adding new ones?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-M7nHCiNUOwFt6Us3r8alutZLm9qMt4s9951uo8jqO4UwJ1hziseL6O3ndFyigx6+LREfZqnhHxYjKRJ8ZQ69DQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <style>
            rect{
                stroke: #ffffff;
            }
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            let board_state = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
                               
            const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
            let height = window.innerHeight || (window.document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.document.body.clientHeight); 
            let width = height / 2;
            svg.attr("height", height).attr("width", width);
            
            let board = svg.append("g");
            let x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).domain([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
            let y = d3.scaleBand().range([0, height]).domain([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]);
            let color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                          .domain([0, 1])
                          .range(["#aaaaaa", "red"]);
            
            let local = d3.local();
            
            function drawBoard(){
                board.selectAll("g")
                 .data(board_state)
                 .join(
                    enter => enter.append("g"),
                    update => update,
                    exit => exit.remove()
                 )
                 .selectAll(".field")
                 .data( function(d,i){ 
                    local.set(this, i)
                    return d;
                 })
                 .join(
                    enter => enter.append("rect"),
                    update => update,
                    exit => exit.remove()
                 )
                 .attr("x", function(d, i){ return x(i); })
                 .attr("y", function(d){ return y(local.get(this)); })
                 .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
                 .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                 .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d); });
            }

            drawBoard();
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `.selectAll` you are selecting by class name but never assign that class.  This means your selection will be empty and all the data will be "entering" again.

Easy fix:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-M7nHCiNUOwFt6Us3r8alutZLm9qMt4s9951uo8jqO4UwJ1hziseL6O3ndFyigx6+LREfZqnhHxYjKRJ8ZQ69DQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <style>
            rect{
                stroke: #ffffff;
            }
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            let board_state = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
                               
            const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
            let height = 600 //window.innerHeight || (window.document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.document.body.clientHeight); 
            let width = height / 2;
            svg.attr("height", height).attr("width", width);
            
            let board = svg.append("g");
            let x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).domain([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
            let y = d3.scaleBand().range([0, height]).domain([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]);
            let color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                          .domain([0, 1])
                          .range(["#aaaaaa", "red"]);
            
            let local = d3.local();
            
            function drawBoard(){
                board.selectAll("g")
                 .data(board_state)
                 .join(
                    enter => enter.append("g"),
                    update => update,
                    exit => exit.remove()
                 )
                 .selectAll(".field")
                 .data( function(d,i){ 
                    local.set(this, i)
                    return d;
                 })
                 .join(
                    enter => enter.append("rect").attr("class", "field"),
                    update => update,
                    exit => exit.remove()
                 )
                 .attr("x", function(d, i){ return x(i); })
                 .attr("y", function(d){ return y(local.get(this)); })
                 .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
                 .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                 .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d); });
            }

            drawBoard();
            setTimeout(() => {
              board_state[7][9] = 1;
              drawBoard();
            }, 3000)
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes totally sense. I completely forgot to add the class.